# How to remove specyfic shapes from Canvas in WPF?

Tags: wpf, canvas, collections

I have list of lines.

```
public List<Line> someList = new List<Line>();
```

These lines are added to `canvas1.Children` collection.

Now I want to remove all of them from canvas, but leave other shapes there.

How can I do it?

I tried to set all `someList` items to null, but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate over `someList` and call `Remove`:

```
foreach (Line line in someList)
{
    canvas1.Children.Remove(line);
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. Its working. I had dumb bug in other part of my code :)